# How to receive websockets in multiple threads

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, async-await

I am using the library `websockets`.

When trying to receive data from the function of receiving websockets in multiple threads, I get an error. I can't get over it. I need your help!

My code:

```html
async def receive_ws():
    async with websockets.connect(uri, extra_headers=VALID_HEADERS) as websocket:
        while True:
            result = await websocket.recv()
            print(result)


async def streams():
    list_streams = []
    for i in range(0, 100):
        list_streams.append(str(i))
    for j in list_streams:
        await asyncio.to_thread(receive_ws)


asyncio.run(streams())
```

My error:

```html
C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:1891: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'receive_ws' was never awaited
  handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py:79: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'receive_ws' was never awaited
  del work_item
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: instead of `await asyncio.to_thread(receive_ws)` cant you just do `await receive_ws()`

Comment: My goal - to provide websockets from multiple threads simultaneously

Comment: Do you really need multiple threads?

Comment: Yes, I need to run in multiple threads at the same time

Comment: Then why use async, normally you can just use async and avoid threads if you only network bound which from your code seems like you are so why do you need threads?

Comment: I need to do load testing of a service. For this, I want to receive websockets on multiple threads at the same time

Comment: do you mean you want to do multiprocessing. Multithreading and multiprocessing isnt the same thing. In multithreading the process will switch between threads when threads perform actions but only one thread can ever be doing something at that time. So in multithreading only one request can ever be sent at the same time, however once its sent another thread can be switched in to send another request while the first thread waits for its reply. You can acheive the same thing with async. so again do you really need to use multithreading or multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

You can use asyncio to gather your list of co-routines to be run. Below is an example using async sleep to exaggerate network delay or expensive compute on the request before its returned. Like threads requests are sent one after the other and dont need to wait until one is finished to start the next one. The co-routines will be weaved in and out of the process as needed and when responses are returned.

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime


async def receive_ws():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://echo.websocket.org/") as websocket:
        num = randint(1, 10)
        print(f"{datetime.now()} - sending random num: {num}")
        await websocket.send(f"{num}")
        await asyncio.sleep(num)
        result = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"{datetime.now()} - received random num: {result}")


async def streams():
    await asyncio.tasks.gather(*[receive_ws() for _ in range(10)])


asyncio.run(streams())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2021-05-31 22:05:29.176031 - sending random num: 3
2021-05-31 22:05:29.261444 - sending random num: 6
2021-05-31 22:05:29.263445 - sending random num: 1
2021-05-31 22:05:29.279507 - sending random num: 5
2021-05-31 22:05:29.281536 - sending random num: 3
2021-05-31 22:05:29.282536 - sending random num: 5
2021-05-31 22:05:29.291587 - sending random num: 8
2021-05-31 22:05:29.306629 - sending random num: 5
2021-05-31 22:05:29.307628 - sending random num: 5
2021-05-31 22:05:29.310629 - sending random num: 1
2021-05-31 22:05:30.266371 - received random num: 1
2021-05-31 22:05:30.298470 - received random num: 1
2021-05-31 22:05:32.192146 - received random num: 3
2021-05-31 22:05:32.300554 - received random num: 3
2021-05-31 22:05:34.278179 - received random num: 5
2021-05-31 22:05:34.278179 - received random num: 5
2021-05-31 22:05:34.326365 - received random num: 5
2021-05-31 22:05:34.326365 - received random num: 5
2021-05-31 22:05:35.265017 - received random num: 6
2021-05-31 22:05:37.289913 - received random num: 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the work you've done. All the same, I need several streams to work on receiving websockets at the same time.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need multiprocessing not multithreading. As threading cannot do more than one thing at a time.